# how to check if a nested key exists in a map

Tags: clojure

I want to check if every key given in a vector `[:e [:a :b] [:c :d]]` exists in a map.

`{:e 2 :a {:b 3} :c {:d 5}}`

I could write the following to check -

```
(def kvs {:e 2 :a {:b 3} :c {:d 5}})    
(every? #(contains? kvs %) [[:e] [:a :b] [:c :d]])
```

However the above would fail as contains doesnt check the key one level deep like update-in does. How do I accomplish the above ?

Answer (score 3):

An improvement on murtaza's basic approach, which also works when the map has nil or false values:

```
(defn contains-every? [m keyseqs]
  (let [not-found (Object.)]
    (not-any? #{not-found}
              (for [ks keyseqs]
                (get-in m ks not-found)))))

user> (contains-every? {:e 2 :a {:b 3} :c {:d 5}}
                       [[:e] [:a :b] [:c :d]])
true
user> (contains-every? {:e 2 :a {:b 3} :c {:d 5}}
                       [[:e] [:a :b] [:c :d :e]])
false
```

Comment: I'd suggest to swap `defn` and `let` lines, so that `not-found` is created only once, and not per function invocation.

Comment: @dimagog I might write it that way in code for myself, but it seems to be a style that clojure programmers don't appreciate. Allocating a new object is one of the fastest things the JVM can do, so it's not terribly expensive to do it the "slow" way. And where do you stop? We ought to close over `#{not-found}` as well, really. By that point the function looks pretty ugly, for a trivial performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The following does it -

```
(every? #(get-in kvs %) [[:e] [:a :b] [:c :d]])
```

Any other answers also welcome !

Comment: This will return false if a key is there but it has a nil/false value

Comment: This won't work, check for the following `(every? #(get-in kvs %) [[:e] [:a :c :b] [:c :d] ])`. Keys order matters with `get-in` with a map.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: The ordering is part of the question, [:a :b] means check if the map has :a key and :b key inside the value of :a key

Comment: @Ankur, Yes, but the OP doen't mean it! Need edit the question with more details/requirement!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
(every? #(if (vector? %)
           (contains? (get-in  kvs (drop-last %)) (last %))
           (contains? kvs %)) [:e [:a :b] [:c :d]])
```